# How to count CheckBoxList checked using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have search with the following keyword but couldn't find.

javascript CheckBoxList api

jquery CheckBoxList checked count

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following should give you the total number of checked checkboxes on the page

```
var count = $(':checkbox:checked').length;
```

If you want to restrict it only to a given CheckBoxList you could assign this checkboxlist some class and then:

```
var count = $('.someClass :checkbox:checked').length;
```

Comment: Thanks Darin! I was trying to go about it in a for loop and return false for no post back, but this is perfect.